# Voximplant forward the call to another phone number

Tags: voximplant

During a call in Voxpmplant, I want to forward the call to another phone number. Do I understand correctly, that I need to call another user via the VoxEngine.callUser method and then unite them via VoxEngine.easyProcess method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call a user via VoxEngine.callUser, or VoxEngine.callPSTN, or VoxEngine.callSIP, and then unite the calls via the sendMediaBetween(call1, call2) method.

https://voximplant.com/docs/references/voxengine/voxengine/sendmediabetween